# How to expand the pixel coordinates in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, coordinates

I want develop an matlab's application that can show the bounding box to the object in the image.

I have detected the object, and cropped it.

And now, for the boundng box, i just have to add 10 in all my pixel.

For exmpl:

```
       x=x+10;  
       y=y+10;  
       w=w+10;  
       h=h+10;
```

I use imcrop function.
But the problem is that i dont understand how to get the pixel's coordinates from imcrop.

```
     [I_crop, I_rect]=imcrop(ImSeq(:,:,1),[])
     I_rect=floor(I_rect);

     final_rect=I_rect;
     for t=1:NumImages
       cur_r=final_rect(2);
       cur_c=final_rect(1);
         for r= cur_r -10:cur_r+10
           for c=cur_c-10:cur_c+10
             temp= abs(I_crop-ImSeq(r:r+I_rect(4),c:c+I_rect(3),t));
```

what is `final_rect(2)`, `final_rect(1)`, `I_rect(4)` and `I_rect(3)`?
How i can get the coordinates of x,y,w,h of the cropped image??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `[I2 rect] = imcrop(I)`,  `rect` is the cropping rectangle, a four-element position vector. Within the original image, the cropped area is defined by:

`rect(2)` the current row
`rect(1)` the current column
`rect(3)` is the width 
`rect(4)` the height.

Comment: How if i use the automatically crop.    
I have :   

                lminc=min(n_bb);lmaxc=max(n_bb);     
                lmaxr=max(m_bb);lminr=min(m_bb);       

what i have to change in for r, for c and temp??

Comment: `r = lminr:lmaxr` and `c = lminc:lmaxc`. `temp` depends on what you want to acheive.